# How to write an offline silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

How to write an offline silverlight application? In which I have a database running on databse server,Application running on application server ,however if user wants to run the application in offline mode then the same ui can be seen to him in offline also all the data stored locally in the files which can be synchronised later.

Answer (score 5):

Your question can be divided in two I think:

1) How to build out-of-browser Silverlight applications?

You can do that since Silverlight 3. See for example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882515.aspx

2) How to have offline access to data that is normally online?

You need to implement a cache mechanism that locally stores the data using isolated storage. See for example here: http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2008/06/26/data-focused-silverlight-demo.aspx

Comment: What data synch mechanism used when do online??

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could choose to cache the SL control using  < IE 7.0 'Make page available offline'...  This page could then use navigator.Online to check if the browser is working offline...  If so, you could elect to use Isolated Storage or Google gears via JavaScript bridge...

Note: IE 7.0 and above [you could make an RSS feed](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.internetexplorer.general&tid=f6bd4244-942d-4c39-9301-e1b797a42c77&cat=&lang=&cr=&sloc=&p=1) for your page available to enable the same behavior...

Seems [navigator.Online has been around in IE for sometime](http://www.mail-archive.com/whatwg-whatwg.org@lists.whatwg.org/msg01715.html).

IE 8.0 even has an event handler for [offline mode toggle...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304129(VS.85).aspx)